# .htaccess redirect with queries?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I've been searching on the net of how to solve this problem that I'm having, but I haven't found a solution yet, I'd be happy if you could help me out.

Here is the thing; I want this link to be redirected

> www.example.net/pages/posts/postview.php?id=233

to this link

> http://www.example.net/post/title/id

I was able to redirect simple links without query stuff, but this I haven't been able to solve...yet.

Comment: your question has .htaccess tags. so i'm going out on a limb and saying you have done some htaccess. what have you tried with htaccess?

Comment: @anurupr I tried what Neil Masters said, but it didn't work

Comment: so your url is not fixed? are there more parameters to come?

Comment: yeah. I want it to be from "www.example.net/pages/posts/postview.php?id=233&title=hello" to "www.example.net/pages/posts/postview.php?id=233"

Comment: so the title parameter should be ignored right?

Comment: oh sorry man, I gave you the wrong second link. I meant this: http://www.example.net/post/title/id